# I want to be able to run my Python through Atom like i have been able to do on my phone with dcoder

Tags: python-3.x, cmd, atom-editor

So Im very new to programming and computers in general... Over the last couple months i have learned everything i know on my phone using Dcoder with android. I have been searching for a program that is similar but on a laptop that can compile my .py files. So i downloaded Atom and have installed atom-python-run and other packages to run my code through the terminal (even though I would rather it compile like on Dcoder) but it says that python is not a file... so i changed the path in the control panel to the right folder but now it says no pyvenv.cfg file... in cmd it doesnt work when i type in python but it works when i type in py... idk

honestly if anyone knows how i can get a program like dcoder on my laptop i would greatly appreciate it... i am way more familiar with phones than i am with laptops... but im trying to learn.

I have tried everything. This is my last hope before giving up

error message one on atom: windows cannot find python make sure you have spelled it right

is there anyway to just get it to search for py????

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run python using the Atom editor you must first load python into Atom. This is simple. Go to [this site](https://atom.io/search?page=2&q=python) and install the extension 'laungage python'. Then search for and install the package 'Script'. Script will successfully run your python files. Run Atom and enter your python file. Then go to the packages menu and click on Script. I haven't been able to get Python Runner or Code runner to run my python files, only Script.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I ended up installing pycharm and using their console instead...

Comment: That should work!  Glad you got your problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Dcoder has a web app also at https://code.dcoder.tech, Dcoder uses cloud storage, makes it easier to switch between phone and laptop to code when needed.